# polymer paper-dialog app-drawer-layout

Tags: polymer, paper-dialog

I am fairly new to Polymer and working within the app-drawer-template as part of the App Toolbox tutorial.

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>

<my-shared shared-data="{{sharedData}}"></my-shared>
  <!-- Drawer content -->
  <app-drawer>
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="[[routeData.page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="view1" href="/view1">View One</a>
      <a name="view2" href="/view2">View Two</a>
      <a name="view3" href="/view3">View Three</a>
      <a name="new-view" href="/new-view">Another View</a>
      <a name="order" href="/order">Order view</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

    <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div title>Sam's App</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <iron-pages role="main" selected="[[routeData.page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
      <my-view1 name="view1" shared-data="{{sharedData}}"></my-view1>
      <my-view2 name="view2" shared-data="{{sharedData}}"></my-view2>
      <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
      <my-new-view name="new-view"></my-new-view>
      <my-order name="order" shared-data="{{sharedData}}"></my-order>
    </iron-pages>

  </app-header-layout>

</app-drawer-layout>
```

In one of the pages I created a paper-dialog element

```
<paper-button on-tap="toggleTestDialog">Toggle Test Dialog</paper-button>

  <paper-dialog id="idTestDialog" style="width: 100%; background-color: blue;">
    <h2>Dialog Title</h2>
    <div>Content to dialog</div>
  </paper-dialog>
```

When the drawer is closed the dialog box is centered to the  [main content section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEVLZ.png) However when the drawer is open, the dialog box does not fit into the main content section but [is covered by the drawer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8LOH.png)I have tried to use the positionTarget property to position the paper-dialog box but have been unable to center the dialog to the main content section within app-header-layout tag.I also only added the width: 100% to clearly show this issue. I am not sure if I am using the positionTarget properly, or if there is another issue I am missing.

```
toggleTestDialog: function () {
      this.$.idTestDialog.positionTarget = this.$.idContainingDiv;
      console.log(this.$.idTestDialog.positionTarget);

      this.$.idTestDialog.open();
    }
```

Comment: The main reason behind that is the `drawer` does not `re-position` the main element it just opens on top of it. As a result the main element is still taking the `100% width` of the viewport and your `dialog box` is still centered to it.

Comment: thanks @a1626, I am still a bit confused on that since the main element does appear to be repositioned when the drawer is opened, or else I would not see the app-toolbar and app-header when it is open. It looks like the only thing not being re-positioned is the dialog box itself?

Comment: UPDATE: I worked around this with media queries on the left position of the dialog box adding the width of the drawer when it is greater than the responsive width